# Spinner - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, spinners

Preciso criar um spinner pelo código de programação e definir:

- layout_height:     match_parent
- layout_weight:     10
- layout_width: wrap_content

Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);

> sp.Layout_height ???

Comment: Tem algo feito? O que exatamente não está conseguindo fazer? Coloque o código aqui para facilitar a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para alterar programaticamente o tamanho de uma view utilize o `LayoutParameters`.

**Exemplo:**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parametros = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 10);
Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);
sp.LayoutParameters = parametros;
```

Lembrando que esse construtor tem a seguinte assinatura: `LayoutParams(int width, int height, int weight)`

Ou se preferir pode fazer dessa forma:

```
Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parametros = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)sp.LayoutParameters;
parametros.Height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
parametros.Width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
parametros.Weight = 10;
```

Espero ter ajudado.